# Split GridView in ViewGroups for each row

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewgroup

I have a program that creates a dinamic GridView with a custom adapter, and I want to go around the elements using a for loop.

The problem is for example in a 4 x 4 grid the GridView has only 1 ViewGroup so it has 16 elements, but I want to have 4 ViewGroups to loop in each group separatly.

How can I do that?

My GridView Layout:

```
<GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.example.dante.puzzle.Joc"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

And My Custom Adapter Cell:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginTop="3px"
                android:textSize="20px" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In resume, I want to iterate like this:

```
gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        final int size = gridView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) gridView.getChildAt(i);
            int childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();
            for (int k = 0; k < childSize; k++) {
                if (gridChild.getChildAt(k) instanceof TextView) {
                    gridChild.getChildAt(k).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
         }
```

But I can't because my GridView has only 1 (16) ViewGroup, not 4 (4) ViewGroups.

Comment: can you open the problem plz

Comment: Why do you need to go 4 by 4?

Comment: I need/want to go 4 by 4 because I need to change the text of the TextViews  horitzontally or vertically (it's a game and the player moves the content of the cell only in horizontal or vertical to match a given pattern), so it's better if I can group the elements instead of have only one group with all of them.

Comment: so whats the problem with creating `View[][] viewMatrix` 2D array? you know number of columns after all...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not expert in android, I try to use that you say. Thanks for the quick answer!